# How to Inject strings into tinyMCE from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tinymce

My background_script.js sends a message such as this:

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {message: 'insert_string'}, function(){} );
    });
};
```

The receiver.js catches this as:

```
function insert_string() {
    var field = document.activeElement;
    if(field.tagName == "IFRAME") {
        field = field.contentDocument.activeElement;
    }
    field.value += 'This is my string';
}
```

Now, the extension works perfectly well on regular editable fields and textareas (it even works properly in tinyMCE on the textarea-tab!) but in the case of Visual-tab of tinyMCE I can't get this to work. I have noticed that the Visual-tab, as it's a WYSIWYG editor, is special and the only way I so far have figured out on how to solve this issue would be to mimic tinyMCE's behaviour for updating the Visual-tab. However, I would like to know if there's something simple and obvious I've missed. If not, how would I go about editing the Visual-tab contents?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to issue to fill the editor is

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').setContent('This is my string');
```